# How to store credit card on Paypal Vault?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

The Paypal REST API has an endpoint that allows saving a customer credit card information into the vault.

The problem is that I don't want to manually deal with credit card information on my frontend (and I believe it wouldn't be PCI compliant?) and then call that endpoint to store it in the vault.

Is there any other way to store a credit card in the vault? Maybe using hosted fields/pages? I've been searching the documentation but I haven't found any way to do this.